# Deploying a custom build of ClearCanvas

Tags: installation, clearcanvas

What exactly does the ClearCanvas installer do besides copying the executable and dlls to `C:\Program Files\clearcanvas\clearcanvas workstation`?

I was able to deploy a custom build of ClearCanvas by installing SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0, running the CCWorkstation2.0SP1x64.exe installer (from the CCDicomViewer2.0SP1x64.exe package on SourceForge), and then replacing the .exe, .dll, and .config files and the actionmodel.xml file with the corresponding files from my custom build.  However, this is hardly an ideal way to deploy an application.  The project for building the installer is missing from the github repository.

To clarify, I am talking specifically about deploying ClearCanvas ImageViewer (not ImageServer or WebStation, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The Workstation also has a Service you should look ShredHostService Project